# Django OAuth2 Error: invalid_client and client_id=None when client_id has been provided

Tags: django, authentication, oauth-2.0, google-apps, django-socialauth

I am using django-social-auth for google apps authentication for my django project. I obtained the client id and secret key from Google api console for my domain. And plugged in the values in my app as follows:

```
    **settings.py**

      MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
      'social_auth.middleware.SocialAuthExceptionMiddleware',
      )

     LOGIN_URL = '/login/google-oauth2/'
     LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/profile'
     LOGIN_ERROR_URL = '/login-error/'

     AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
      'social_auth.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2Backend',
      'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
     )

    TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
     "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
     "social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends",
    )

    SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('google',)
    SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'new_social_auth_user'

    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '***.apps.googleusercontent.com'
    GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '****'
    GOOGLE_WHITE_LISTED_DOMAINS = ['127.0.0.1:8000']

    SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'socialauth_complete'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'
    SOCIAL_AUTH_RAISE_EXCEPTIONS = False
    SOCIAL_AUTH_PROCESS_EXCEPTIONS = 'social_auth.utils.log_exceptions_to_messages'  

    INSTALLED_APPS = (
            'social_auth', )
```

...

```
    **urls.py**

     from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
     from django.contrib import admin
     from django.views.generic import TemplateView
     from django.contrib.auth.views import logout
     admin.autodiscover()

     urlpatterns = patterns('',

     url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
     url(r'', include('social_auth.urls')),
     url(r'^$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="login.html")),                 
     url(r'^logout/$', logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='gauth_logout'),
     url(r'^profile/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="profile.html")),
     )
```

...

```
     **login.html**

     <p>Use your work email credentials to sign in to this application: 
     <a href="{% url 'socialauth_begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Sign In</a>
      </p>
```

The problem is that when I click on sign in I am redirected to the Error: Invalid_client page with the details:

```
      Request Details
      cookie_policy_enforce=false
      scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile
      response_type=code
      redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/google-oauth2/
      state=WZWyJgDRfeW4RneRynqSZ3nSy0Bzs0v6
      client_id=None
```

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile&state=WZWyJgDRfeW4RneRynqSZ3nSy0Bzs0v6&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/complete/google-oauth2/&response_type=code&client_id=None

Even though I have provided the correct client_id in my project, the page (and as can be seen from the url) says that it has not been provided. If I plug it manually in the url, I am redirected to the permissions page though.

Also when I accept the permissions I get an **AuthCanceled at /complete/google-oauth2/** error. Is it that my project is not reading the social_auth settings correctly?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

i was having the same problem just change

```
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = '***.apps.googleusercontent.com'
GOOGLE_OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = '****'
```

To

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_KEY = '****.apps.googleusercontent.com'
SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_SECRET ='****'
```

in the settings.py file

Comment: I have the same issue with the correct vars even. It works locally just fine but on my server it passes client_id=None in the api call...